# How do I start Chrome or Edge in a new isolated window with DevTools open?

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge, google-chrome-devtools

Sometimes I want to open Chrome or Edge just to access its JavaScript console for a quick scripting experiment, similar to that in Node/Deno [REPL mode](https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-use-the-nodejs-repl).

I don't want to use <kbd>F12</kbd> with a currently open Chrome window/tab to avoid any interfering with its web page's context.

Is there a command line option for that, so I can create a desktop shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering to my future self. To start Chrome as a new isolated window with DevTools open, from CLI in Windows:

`chrome.exe  --start-maximized --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs --user-data-dir=%TMP%\chrome -profile-directory=Default about:blank`

The same works for Edge, just use a different `user-data-dir` folder:

`msedge.exe  --start-maximized --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs --user-data-dir=%TMP%\msedge -profile-directory=Default about:blank`

As a one-off, once in DevTools, hit F1 and enable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1-9</kbd> shortcuts. Then <kbd>Ctrl+2</kbd> is for JavaScript console in Chrome, <kbd>Ctrl+3</kbd> in Edge.